# react-native-navigation Want to access super view which all tab views are rendered on

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using `react-native-navigation` for my tab view based app.

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs,
  appStyle: {
    orientation: 'portrait',
    tabBarBackgroundColor: 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)',
  },
  tabsStyle: {
    tabBarButtonColor: DARK_GRAY,
    tabBarSelectedButtonColor: DARK_GRAY,
    tabBarHideShadow: true,
  },
  animationType: 'fade',
});
```

I am wondering which is the super view of all tab views?
How can I overwrite it?

Currently I want to send an event thru the entire app, but I can't access to the super view so I have to add listeners in all views.

I want to add one listener in super view. How can I implement it using `react-native-navigation`?

Comment: What do you want to listen to? The view you are referring to is defined in native and not accessible to Js.

Comment: So I can't show a view over the entire tab view?